How can I quickly create markdown callouts and quote blocks?
With hotkeys / automatic actions, I want to:

Put text inside either on the current line in normal mode, or all visually selected lines, into a callout or quote block as well as
Select lines in the callout or quote and remove the > quote marks on said lines.

Remark: Callouts are like quotes but with an extra line on top: > [!Callout Title].
Text
Text
↓

> [!Callout Title]
> text
> text

I just setup LuaSnip with two snippets with fmt, and looked up how to add visual selections or the clipboard (perhaps as nodes) for Lua snippets, but didn't find any answers. What would be the best way(s) to do this?

It might help if you shared what you already tried. Are you looking for a solution with a specific plugin?

I'll take any answers, though any via Luasnip would be nice.

I would do the following:
function! Quote() range
    let r=winsaveview()
    call append(a:firstline - 1, '[!Callout Text]')
    if a:firstline == a:lastline
      s/^/> /
    else
      '<,'>s/^/> /
    endif
    call winrestview(r)
endfunction

vnoremap <leader>aq :call Quote()<CR>
nnoremap <leader>aq :call Quote()<CR>

function! UnQuote() range
    let r=winsaveview()
    '<,'>g/>\s\+\[!/d
    if a:firstline == a:lastline
      s/^> //
    else
      '<,'>s/^> //
    endif
    call winrestview(r)
endfunction

vnoremap <leader>rq :call UnQuote()<CR>
nnoremap <leader>rq :call UnQuote()<CR>

Or the lua version of the same:
vim.cmd([[
function! Quote() range
    let r=winsaveview()
    call append(a:firstline - 1, '[!Callout Text]')
    if a:firstline == a:lastline
      s/^/> /
    else
      '<,'>s/^/> /
    endif
    call winrestview(r)
endfunction

function! UnQuote() range
    let r=winsaveview()
    '<,'>g/>\s\+\[!/d
    if a:firstline == a:lastline
      s/^> //
    else
      '<,'>s/^> //
    endif
    call winrestview(r)
endfunction
]])

local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }
vim.keymap.set({"v", "n"}, "<leader>aq", ":call Quote()<CR>", opts)
vim.keymap.set({"v", "n"}, "<leader>rq", ":call UnQuote()<CR>", opts)

Or in even more lua:
function quote()
    local firstline = vim.fn.line("v")
    local lastline = vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0)[1]
    local r = vim.fn.winsaveview()
    vim.fn.append(firstline - 1, '[!Callout Text]')
    if firstline == lastline then
      vim.cmd("s/^/> /")
    else
      vim.cmd(firstline .. "," .. lastline .. "s/^/> /")
    end
    vim.fn.winrestview(r)
    vim.cmd("noh")
end

function unquote()
    local firstline = vim.fn.line("v")
    local lastline = vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0)[1]
    local r = vim.fn.winsaveview()
    vim.cmd(firstline .. "," .. lastline .. [[g/>\s\+\[!/d]])
    if firstline == lastline then
      vim.cmd("s/^> //")
    else
      vim.cmd(firstline .. "," .. lastline .. "s/^> //")
    end
    vim.fn.winrestview(r)
end

local opts = { noremap = true, silent = true }
vim.keymap.set({"v", "n"}, "<leader>aq", quote, opts)
vim.keymap.set({"v", "n"}, "<leader>rq", unquote, opts)


You don't remove a callout title in UnQuote(), do you? I can't blame you, I dodged this part completely. Just when I decided I was too lazy to go into functions, you posted your function-based answer :-D

I think I do with '<,'>g/>\s\+\[!/d. But maybe I didn't capture your question correctly.

Yes, of course. I missed that line. Sorry for that.

You can write user-defined commands to add block quotes and callouts in plain Vimscript:
:command! -buffer -range=1 -bar BlockQuote <line1>,<line2>s/^/> / | nohlsearch
:command! -buffer -range=1 -bar Callout <line1>,<line2>BlockQuote | <line1> | normal O> [!Callout Title]
:noremap <buffer> <F2> :BlockQuote<CR>
:noremap <buffer> <F3> :Callout<CR>

The first command prefixes each line in the range with >  to create a block quote.
It then turns off search highlighting for convenience.
The second command calls the first command to add a block quote and inserts a line with the callout title above.
The third and fourth lines are simply mappings for the F2 and F3 keys to call the commands.
Feel free to pick any other keys you like.
All the commands and mappings are buffer-local, to have them available only for markdown files.
More information on user-defined commands can be found in :help :command.
As for toggling these things, you can put some more complexity into the commands (that would probably be the time to consider functions).
You would also have to think about edge cases, e.g. when one line is prefixed with >  and another one isn't.
I'd rather go with an old fashioned 0xx to unquote a single line or :'<,'>s/^> // to remove them from a range.
A simple dd should take care of a callout title.

I am using the lua provided by Vivian De Smedt, and edited the functions, so that they work with nested quotes and callouts, it asks for a callout title, and it doesn't throw a backwards range error
function quote(callout)
  local firstline = vim.fn.line("v")
  local lastline = vim.fn.line(".")
  local quotes = string.match(vim.fn.getline("."), "^[>%s]*")
  quotes = quotes and quotes.."> " or "> "
  if firstline > lastline then firstline, lastline = lastline, firstline end
  pcall(vim.cmd, firstline .. "," .. lastline .. "s/^\\(>\\|\\s\\)\\+//")
  vim.cmd(firstline .. "," .. lastline .. "s/^/"..quotes.."/")
  if callout then vim.fn.append(firstline - 1, quotes.."[!"..vim.fn.input("Callout Title: ").."]") end
  vim.cmd("noh")
end

function unquote()
  local firstline = vim.fn.line("v")
  local lastline = vim.api.nvim_win_get_cursor(0)[1]
  if firstline > lastline then firstline, lastline = lastline, firstline end
  local r = vim.fn.winsaveview()
  vim.cmd(firstline .. "," .. lastline .. [[g/>\s\+\[!/d]])
  if firstline == lastline then
    vim.cmd("s/^> //")
  else
    vim.cmd(firstline .. "," .. lastline .. "s/^> //")
  end
  vim.fn.winrestview(r)
end

